# Is it possible to use Firebase ML Kit Text Recognition and Barcode Scanner at the same time?

Tags: android, firebase, google-vision, firebase-mlkit

I already make the app for Text Recognition and Barcode Scanner separately. But is it possible if i want to use Text Recognition and Barcode Scanner at the same time at Live Stream?

I confused after i read this code

```
mCameraSource.setMachineLearningFrameProcessor(barcodeScanningProcessor);
```

Is that indicate that only one camerasource per one MachineLearning?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, however the sample code you are using is tailored for using one frame processor at a time.

One way to achieve what you are looking for is to process each frame individually, which would allow you to pass it to multiple APIs.

[CameraView](https://natario1.github.io/CameraView/docs/frame-processing.html) is one package that allows frame processing. You may want to throttle and only take one out of every X frames, since processing a frame is computationally intensive.

```
cameraView.addFrameProcessor(new FrameProcessor() {
   @Override
   @WorkerThread
   public void process(Frame frame) {
       byte[] data = frame.getData();
       int rotation = frame.getRotation();
       long time = frame.getTime();
       Size size = frame.getSize();
       int format = frame.getFormat();

       // Process frame
       // This is where you'd pass the image to the Text recognition API
       // and then to the Barcode scanning API.

   }
}
```

You'd process each frame as described in the documentation for [text recognition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text#1.-run-the-text-recognizer), and similarly for [barcode scanning](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes#1.-configure-the-barcode-detector).